# In SP 2010 is it possible to import a Content Type into multiple libraries at once?

Tags: content

I have 30+ libraries that I need to add a Content Type to. I know how to do this manually for each library, but I'm wondering if there is a way to import it across all site collections and libraries?

The libraries were created based on a library template, any way to add the content type to the library template and have it flow down to the already existing libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to have a **content type hub** where to create your **content type** and then **publish it to all your sites in the farm**. Thus, you will have the content type available everywhere, whenever you need it.

See the following blog post on how to create a content type hub: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Plan-your-SharePoint-2010-Content-Type-Hub-carefully.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I already have a content type hub, what I meant was that I need to add a new content type to already existing libraries. I'm wondering if there's a way to do that across a whole site collection or if I have to manually add it for each library.

Comment: Right, apart from attaching the content type manually to each library, you could have a PowerShell script where you specify all the libraries you have and the content type you want to attach to them. I presume you don't have such a script (unfortunately, I don't either), plus it would take you more time to write one than "visiting" each library using the web interface (unless you're familiar with the SharePoint API), so in this case you have to do the manual work; unless you have the time to write the PS script, so you can also use it for other content types and libraries/lists in the future.